# Form Validation in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a simple Angular app using twitter-bootstrap and jquery to display the data of Employees. 4 data are hardcoded and is displayed in the table as in the image attached to it. I have added "Add Employee" button which pops up the Modal box which contains form to add the employees information. I have used the Validation as well but it submits empty data too.

[image: This is the initial page after i run the app]

[image: The error message shows but blank data can be submitted!]

[image: This is the table after submtting blank data from the Modal]

Here are the components:

`employee-data.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i= index;">
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control"
                    type="number" 
                    min="1" [(ngModel)]="employee.id" 
                    [disabled]="!employee.isEditable">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="employee.name" 
                    [disabled]="!employee.isEditable"
                    >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="employee.address" 
                    [disabled]="!employee.isEditable"
                    >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="employee.gender" 
                    [disabled]="!employee.isEditable"
                    >
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    [(ngModel)]="employee.company" 
                    [disabled]="!employee.isEditable"
                    >
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <!-- <button (click)="editEmployee(i)">Edit</button> -->
                    <button 
                        class="btn btn-warning"
                        (click)="employee.isEditable=!employee.isEditable"
                        *ngIf="!employee.isEditable" >
                        Edit
                    </button>
                    <button 
                        class="btn btn-warning"
                        (click)="employee.isEditable=!employee.isEditable"
                        *ngIf="employee.isEditable" >
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button 
                        class="btn btn-danger"
                        (click)="deleteEmployee(i)">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-success btn-md" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#myModal">
        Add Employee
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form  [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="addRow()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Id</label>
                        <div>
                            <input 
                                type="number" class="form-control" 
                                formControlName="ModalId" name="id"
                                [(ngModel)]="id"
                                min="1" required />
                            <div 
                                class="alert alert-danger"
                                *ngIf="!userForm.controls['ModalId'].valid && userForm.controls['ModalId'].touched">
                                    Error!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                            <div>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" class="form-control"
                                    formControlName="ModalName" name="name"
                                    [(ngModel)]="name" required />
                            </div>
                            <div 
                                class="alert alert-danger"
                                *ngIf="!userForm.controls['ModalName'].valid && userForm.controls['ModalName'].touched">
                                Error!
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <div>
                            <input 
                                type="text" class="form-control" 
                                formControlName="ModalAddress" name="address"
                                [(ngModel)]="address" required />
                            <div 
                                class="alert alert-danger"
                                *ngIf="!userForm.controls['ModalAddress'].valid && userForm.controls['ModalAddress'].touched">
                                    Error!
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <div>
                            <!-- <input 
                                type="text" class="form-control" name="gender"
                                [(ngModel)]="gender" required /> -->
                            <select class="form-control"
                                [(ngModel)]="gender"
                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                >
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company</label>
                        <div>
                            <input 
                                type="text" class="form-control" 
                                formControlName="ModalCompany" name="company"
                                [(ngModel)]="company" required />
                        </div>
                        <div 
                            class="alert alert-danger"
                            *ngIf="!userForm.controls['ModalCompany'].valid && userForm.controls['ModalCompany'].touched">
                            Error!
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input 
                            type="submit" 
                            value="Submit"
                            class="btn btn-success">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

`employee-data.compenent.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './employee';
//import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { promise } from 'selenium-webdriver';


@Component({
  selector: 'employee-data',
  templateUrl: './employee-data.component.html',
  styles: [``]
})

export class EmployeeDataComponent {

  userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'ModalId': ['', Validators.required],
        'ModalName': ['', Validators.required],
        'ModalAddress': ['', Validators.required],
        'ModalCompany': ['', Validators.required]

    })

  }

  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  gender: string;
  company: string;
  isEditable: boolean;

  //emp: Employee[] = [];

  employees: Employee[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Ram',
        address: 'Kupondole',
        gender: 'Male',
        company: 'XYZ Techno Sales',
        isEditable: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Shyam',
        address: 'Baneshwor',
        gender: 'Male',
        company: 'ABC Enterprises',
        isEditable: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Prashansha',
        address: 'Tripureshwor',
        gender: 'Female',
        company: 'MNO Inc',
        isEditable: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Rita',
        address: 'Ghatthaghar',
        gender: 'Female',
        company: 'Subisu',
        isEditable: false
    }
  ];

  addRow() {
    //prompt("Checking the control!");
    this.employees.push({
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name,
        address: this.address,
        gender: this.gender,
        company: this.company,
        isEditable: this.isEditable

    });
  }

  deleteEmployee(index) {

    this.employees.splice(index, 1);
  }

  editEmployee(index) {

   debugger;
   this.employees[index].isEditable = true;

  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out cause i'm running out of options!

Comment: From a quick glance, you have mixed reactive with template forms.

Comment: The mistake that immediately pops in front of me is that you’re using validators on a form builder, meaning you are using reactive forms and then you have ngModel all over the place for the fields. You can’t have both approaches at the same time. NgModel means it’s template driven and reactive forms means it’s code driven. You have to pick only one of the options

Comment: Just use  #f="ngForm" with your form, send it at submit, and check is it a valid form submission or not by using f.valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing reactive form and template-driven form. I guess what you really want is the reactive form because you are using the `FormBuilder`.

Here's what you need to do.

**Remove template-driven code in your html**

- Remove all the code with  `[(ngModel)]`

**Get the value from the the `userForm`**

The way you get the value from your form is wrong
Change your `addRow()` to this

```
 addRow() {
     this.id =  this.userForm.controls['ModalId'].value;
     this.name = this.userForm.controls['ModalName'].value;
     //more code here.          
     //you get the picture and do the remaining data.
    this.employees.push({
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name,
        address: this.address,
        gender: this.gender,
        company: this.company,
        isEditable: this.isEditable

    });
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SaigalAmatya no problem. glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I agree with brijmcq, choose either template driven or reactive form. Do not mix them both. I would build the form as such, that the object you get from the form can be pushed to your array just as it is. By that, just change the form control names so that they match the `Employee` interface/class.

So just like brijmcq suggests, remove everything related to template driven form - `ngModel` and any validators set in template. Use the form group instead:

```ts
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: ['', [Validators.minLength(1), Validators.required]],
  name: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Then just mark the form control names to your form, and on submit, pass the form values:

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="addRow(userForm.value)">  
  <label>Id</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="id" />
  <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!userForm.controls['id'].valid && userForm.controls['id'].touched">
    Error!
  </div>
  <!-- more code here -->
</form>
```

And then the method for adding the employee, just push the form object to your array and reset form:

```ts
addRow(values) {
  this.employees.push(values);
  this.userForm.reset();
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fei1fj?file=app/app.component.ts)**